How to use python with open file changes on option menu selected file
Hi guys i'm trying to run my python script regardelss of selected file but it dosen't change selected file , i have more then three json files,this is my code :
this is my code :
from tkinter import *  
import os  
import json  
root = Tk()  
root.configure(bg="#4a3b2c")  
root.title("file open test ")  
root.resizable(FALSE, FALSE)

folder = 'profiles'
profile_options = StringVar()   
profile_options.set('test.json')  

profile_menu = OptionMenu(root, profile_options, *[i for i in  os.listdir(folder)])  
profile_menu.place(x=135, y=400)  
final = profile_options.trace_add('write', lambda *args: print(profile_options.get()))  
# printing finale is working and print on selected file but it dosen't open it   
profil_name = StringVar()  
profil_name = profile_options.get()  
# i want to change file selected to run it on option select  
with open("profiles\\"+profil_name, "r") as file:  
   dict = json.load(file)  
   print(profile_options.get())  
width = 1040 # Width   
height = 850 # Height  
screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()  # Width of the screen  
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight() # Height of the screen  
xwidth = (screen_width/2) - (width/2)  
yheigh = (screen_height/2) - (height/2)  
root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (250, 460, xwidth, yheigh))  
root.mainloop()  


Can you provide an example of the content of test.json? Otherwise this isn't something we can readily run as-written. Please try to provide a [mre] that we can run to test things. Also, you print the value of final but you don't use it anywhere else. And the call to profil_name = profile_options.get() only happens once, immediately when your app starts, and then never gets updated again. And your with statement raises Invalid argument: 'profiles\\'

Hi , the profiles is the folder wich have tow json files one named test.json and the othe have test2.json those tow json files have different dictionary values :

[
{
"Name": "adam",
"country": "USA",
"age": "25",
"email": "adam@test.com"
},
{
"Name": "jon",
"country": "FRANCE",
"age": "32",
"email": "Jon@test.com"
}
]

You need a function that will get the selected filename and open the file.

You're setting profil_name before you display the menu and the user selects something from it. You need to do this in a callback function that runs when the user selects from the menu or clicks on a submit button.

Yes but how to use the variable outside callback function def callback(selection):
print("selected file is :",selection)

Open a file inside a function. Why do you need to use a variable outside a function?
